# Domain of $f(x,y) = \ln((16-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-4))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y) = \ln((16-x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2-4))$

I'm stuck in this one because this can be rewritten as:

$$f(x,y) = \ln(16-x^2-y^2) + \ln(x^2+y^2-4)$$

Yet, the domain of the given function is $\{(16-x^2-y^2>0)\land(x^2+y^2-4>0)\} \lor \{(16-x^2-y^2<0)\land (x^2+y^2-4<0)\}$. But the domain of the rewritten on is only $\{(16-x^2-y^2>0)\land(x^2+y^2-4>0)\}$. Which one is the correct one and why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\{(x,y):16-x^2+y^2<0\}\cap\{(x,y):x^2+y^2-4<0\}=\emptyset$, and hence the two domains are the same in different expressions!

Comment: Domain is the ring set by 2 circles: $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=4^2\}\cap\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=2^2\}\; exсluding \;the\; bounds$

Answer (score 1):

When does $log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)$ hold?
Only when $x$ and $y$ are **both greater than zero**! Does that solve your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

In real analysis $\ln(ab)=ln(a)+ln(b)$ is true iff $a>0$ and $b>0$, because in other case the logarithms don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You used $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b$, but this is correct only as long as both $\ln a$ and $\ln b$ are defined. For example $\ln\bigl((-1)\cdot(-1)\bigr)=0$, but the summands in $\ln(-1)+\ln(-1)$ are not defined. Therefore, you need to consider not only the case $a>0\land b>0$, but also $a<0\land b<0$.
2. Accidentally, it did not matter here, because $16-x^2-y^2$ and $x^2+y^2-4$ cannot be negative at the same time (note that their sum is $12$, hence positive).